# How can I display a USB webcam stream from a Raspberry pi with a 5-30min time delay

Tags: streaming-video, webcam, motion

I have used Motion / motion eye to display a USB web cam stream to a website from an Rpi. However, I want the stream to have an adjustable time delay (5-30min) is there anyway I can do this using motion, or if not is there another way to make it work?